# Unusual Font Conversion

Tags: c#, winforms, string, fonts

I have the following string in a file, and it needs to be converted back to a Font object. But I'm not sure how to do this one:

font string:

```
[Font: Name=Segoe UI, Size=14, Units=3, GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]
```

I appreciate any help at all, thank you

bael

Comment: What language, platform, OS are we talking about here???

Comment: Looks like Objective-C. Is this iPhone realted?
@baeltazor your should at least add a tag for the programming language.

Comment: So sorry! I forgot to put the language. It's Visual C# Windows Forms. I'm really sorry about that I don't usually forget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my `FontBuilder` class in the [CC.Utilities](http://ccutilities.codeplex.com) library. It does exactly what you want and provides an extension method `ToStringEx()` to cover the `FontStyle` property that `Font.ToString()` is missing.

I originally wrote it so I could store a `Font` in the registry

**Edit:** Here are the specific files it you're not interested in the whole thing:

**FontBuilder:** http://ccutilities.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40596#648008
**FontExtensions:** http://ccutilities.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40596#664902

Comment: Works perfectly... That's some great work you got there, congrats! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are various [Font constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.font.aspx), [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1ctt98z.aspx) appears to fit the bill:

> **Font Constructor (String, Single, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit, Byte, Boolean)**
>
> Initializes a new Font using the specified size, style, unit, and character set.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *familyName*
>   Type: System.String
>   A string representation of the FontFamily for the new Font.
>
> *emSize*
>   Type: System.Single
>   The em-size of the new font in the units specified by the unit parameter.
>
> *style*
>   Type: System.Drawing.FontStyle
>   The FontStyle of the new font.
>
> *unit*
>   Type: System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit
>   The GraphicsUnit of the new font.
>
> *gdiCharSet*
>   Type: System.Byte
>   A Byte that specifies a GDI character set to use for this font.
>
> *gdiVerticalFont*
>   Type: System.Boolean
>   A Boolean value indicating whether the new Font is derived from a GDI vertical font.

Unless I've misread your string of course.

You would need to parse the string to pass the appropriate values to the constructor.

Comment: You did misunderstand, but that's probably my falt. (haven't slept yet :( )